# Unable to hide back to top button from 1st page

Tags: javascript, html, css

My "back-to-top" button is working correctly.   However, the button is being displayed on the top of the page which I want to hide and display after 20 scrolls. I am using the example from w3 schools. This throws error when I use it in my code. How do I fix it?

```
Error
> (index):115 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
at scrollFunction ((index):115)
at window.onscroll ((index):108)
scrollFunction  @   (index):115
window.onscroll @   (index):108
```

Here's my CSS:

```
#myBtn {
width: 3rem;
height: 3rem;  
align-items:center !important;
    }

#myBtn  svg {
fill: #000;
display: block !important;margin: auto !important;
}
```

My Javascript is as below:

```
/** Scroll back-to-top */
//Get the button
var mybutton = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// When the user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document, show the button
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
mybutton.style.display = "block";
} else {
  mybutton.style.display = "none";
}
}

// When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document
function topFunction() {
document.body.scrollTop = 0;
document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
} 

var url = window.location.href;
            var index = url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
            var filename = url.substr(index);
            if (filename == "index.html") {
                $("top").hide() ;
            };
```

This is my HTML where I define my button.

```
<button class="myBtn" type="button" aria-label="Back to Top" style="float:right;" onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn">
<svg focusable="false" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 32 32" aria-hidden="true" style="will-change: transform;">
<path d="M16 14L6 24 7.4 25.4 16 16.8 24.6 25.4 26 24zM4 8H28V10H4z"></path></svg></button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined the variable `mybutton` outside of the function `scrollFunction()`. Try defining it inside the function, like this:

```
function scrollFunction() {
  var mybutton = document.getElementById("mybtn")
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
    mybutton.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    mybutton.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

or pass it in as a parameter like this:

```
function scrollFunction(mybutton) {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
    mybutton.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    mybutton.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Comment: This works partially. When I scroll the page down and click back to top, it hides the button. However, when I reload the page, back to top button displays  on the top of the page. I declared my button inside the scrollFunction()

Comment: adding display:none removed it upon reload

Comment: Add ```"display:none;"``` in your css.

Answer (score 1):

There is only 1 mistake. Just Change

    `var mybutton = document.getElementById("top"); to 
    var mybutton = document.getElementById("myBtn");`

Apart from this, add `display:none` to the button. So that, it does not display by default.